# Buscar registro específico de una BD con PHP - No muestra nada

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Necesito crear un método que permita buscar y mostrar un registro específico de una base de datos MySQL con PHP. La idea es que muestre la tabla del elemento buscado con sus respectivos atributos.

Tengo un input que leería la ID ingresada para ser buscada en la base de datos, pero no arroja ningún resultado. He aquí el código.

```
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "crud";
  $cod_producto=$_POST['txtBuscar'];

  if(!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "crud")){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
  } else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE 'txtBuscar' ='$cod_producto'";
    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
      if ($result->num_rows>0) {
        echo "<table>";
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row["cod_producto"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["stock"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["precio_compra"]."</td>
          </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
      } else{
        echo "No hay registro";
      }
    } else{
      echo "Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
  }
```

Simplemente no arroja error, solamente muestra el mensaje de "No hay registro".

Comment: Luego de obtener `$cod_producto`, muestralo con un `echo` para confirmar que es lo que estás trayendo. Luego ejecuta esa consulta en mysql, para confirmar que funciona.

Comment: Quita las comillas simples de WHERE 'txtBuscar' solo deja WHERE txtBuscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error está en esta linea:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE 'txtBuscar' ='$cod_producto'";
```

Así como se ve a primera vista, tu $_POST devuelve el valor de txtBuscar, que es lo que el usuario ha ingresado.
Sin embargo, en tu código aparece como que el txtBuscar es un campo de tu tabla.

Recuerda que despues del WHERE va el nombre del campo que se encuentra en la tabla a buscar, seguido de eso viene la variable donde se encuentra el contenido a buscar del campo.

Debería ser algo como esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE cod_producto = '$cod_producto' ";
```